# unable to restore nuget packages from custom feed inside a Podman container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nuget, podman

I have a custom on-premise Azure DevOps nuget feed:

```
http://<network path>/_packaging/IH_DevExpress/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Here is my Containerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY nuget.config .
COPY DxBiDashboard.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore DxBiDashboard.csproj --configfile nuget.config
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build DxBiDashboard.csproj -c Development -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish DxBiDashboard.csproj -c Development -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Here is my nuget.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear/>
    <!-- ensure only the sources defined below are used -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
    <add key="IH_DevExpress" value="http://<network path>/_packaging/IH_DevExpress/nuget/v3/index.json"/>
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The
**RUN dotnet restore DxBiDashboard.csproj --configfile nuget.config**
Step in the Containerfile fails with this exception:

> error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source
> http://network path/_packaging/IH_DevExpress/nuget/v3/index.json.
> Failed to restore /src/DxBiDashboard.csproj (in 16.9 sec).

If I run

```
dotnet restore DxBiDashboard.csproj --configfile nuget.config
```

from the CMD it restores the packages no problem. It's only when I try to build the image with this command:

```
podman build -t dx-webassemly-bi-dashboard .
```

That the error happens.
You can see I'm copying the nuget.config file into the working directory. I have also tried using authentication with PAT in the nuget.config file with no avail (our other feeds are accessible to build pipelines without any authentication tokens). It seems like it's something with the container network configuration but I cannot figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.